# Geometrical interpretation of an overidentified linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

In my econometrics class we talked about Instrumental Variables.

Suppose one has a $n\times k$ matrix $X$ of regressors and a $n\times m$ matrix $Z$ of instrumental variables. Given the matrices are non degenerate and $n>m$, $n>k$, one says that

• The system is **exactly identified** if $m = k$

• The system is **over-identified** if $m > k$

We proved a theorem in the exactly identified case, then we dealt with the other case by restricting to $k$ independent linear combinations of the instrumental variables $z_i$ (the $m$ columns of $Z$ ), i.e. by setting

$$ \tilde{Z} := Z A $$

where $A$ is a non-degenerate $m\times k$ matrix, so that $\tilde{Z}$ is $n\times k$ and we are back to the exactly identified situation.

**My question:** Could one, somehow, interpret the span of the columns of $\tilde{Z}$ to be the projection of the $m$-dimensional space spanned by $Z$ on the $k$-dimensional space spanned by the columns of $A$ ?

Comment: This would be a great question for http://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, I think my question could be asked independently of the economic background, just as a linear algebra question